# How to return rows where text value in one column is part of text value in the other column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

I have a dataset of a following format:

```
dish        | fruit
---------   +------
Orange Pie  | Orange
Stew Soup   | Apple
Pear Cream  | Pear
Wine Drink  | Grapes
Plum Dessert| Plum
```

I'd like to check all the rows and only return ones where name of the fruit is part of the name of the dish.

I've been trying different variations of the following query but it either doesn't work or doesn't get the job done:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE fruit LIKE (CONCAT('%',dish,'%'))
;
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to swap fruit and dish in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the operands of `LIKE` the other way around:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE dish LIKE CONCAT('%', fruit, '%')
```

Note that parentheses around `CONCAT()` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE LOCATE(fruit, dish)
```

Depends on case dependency needed you may need to specify COLLATION.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution works as well, but I was more keen on using the LIKE function because in the actual dataset there were some variations of names that are otherwise not picked up. Should have specified this in the description, sorry.

Comment: @Mark *because in the actual dataset there were some variations of names that are otherwise not picked up.* The matches not found by LOCATE cannot be found by LIKE too. Please provide 2-3 data samples you are speaking about.